# Spring uses "transactionManager" although another one was specified

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I get following error when trying to use Spring transactions:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!
```

Although I have specified another name. Here is code snippet:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionConfig {
...
    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value ="jpaTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    tm.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
    return tm;
}

    @Bean()
    @Qualifier(value="jtaTransactionManager")
    public JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager(UserTransactionManager    atomikosTransactionManager) {
      ......
```

And I use it like this:

```
@Transactional(transactionManager="jpaTransactionManager")
public class UserService {

public Iterable<FVUser> findWithQuery(Specification<FVUser> spec) {
    return repository.findAll(spec);
}
```

Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<FVUser, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<FVUser>  {
```

When debugging I noticed that it correctly uses "jpaTransactionManger" to call service method, but seems to look for a "transactionManager" to call the repository method, although no transaction is specified for it.

Anyone know why Spring is looking for default "transactionManager"  bean in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your spring data configs you should add a parameter to

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(transactionManagerRef = "jtaTransactionManager")
```

the default value is "transactionManager"

Comment: Yes. That was the fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should mark your `PlatformTransactionManager` with `@Bean` too.

And add `@Transactional(transactionManager="jpaTransactionManager")` on your repository. Implementation uses by default @Transactional without parameterers, so that's why it is searching  for default "transactionManager". It was explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10466591/5293754)

Comment: Sorry. It is a bean. I just skipped it by mistake. I updated  the post.

Comment: I have added @Transactional(transactionManager="jpaTransactionManager") also on repository, but same result. Anyway, I don't want repository methods to be transactional. Just to wrap the service method in transaction.