# Spring data JPA. Cascade update works for special cases only

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

### Most important structural description:

In my application is used Spring data JPA.
I have a model part in my application:

```
@Entity
public class Event implements Identifiable {
  // ...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "event", orphanRemoval = true)
  @OrderColumn(name = "order_index")
  private List<Attendee> attendees = new ArrayList<>();
  // ...
}

@Entity
public class Attendee implements Identifiable {
  // ...
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "event_id")
  private Event event;
  // ...
}
```

It should be clear for all who knows `JPA`.

I've implemented test to save an `event`, as result dependent `attendees` collection saves also (hibernate magic used because of correspond relation settings shown in very beginning.)

```
eventRepository.save(event);
```

provides save|update event and replace all old nested attendees with new ones.

### Problem description:

Some times I need use additional handlers in same transaction with saving event. They use repositories also:

```
// transaction starts... some handlers are used
eventRepository.save(event);
// some additional handlers2 are used
// transaction ends
```

If `handlers2` contains any repository operation with independent entity, for example:

```
profileRepository.findAll();
// or
profileRepository.findByEmail("anyEmail");
```

, it fails with exception `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.nextiva.calendar.entity.Attendee`. It seems Attendee collection should be saved because it was not.

To fix the issue I've used workaround like:

```
// transaction starts... some handlers are used
attendeeRepository.save(event.getAttendees());
eventRepository.save(event);
// some additional handlers2 are used
// transaction ends
```

It works now, but I do not like this way.

### Questions:

1. Is it my architectural issue?
2. Is it hibernate issue?
3. How should it be configured without redundant calling `attendeeRepository.save(event.getAttendees());`?

Comment: Did not try to use `eventRepository.saveAndFlush(event)` (from JpaRepository)?

Comment: No, i did not because of spring jpa repositories for example: `org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository`, `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository` do not provide `saveAndFlush`

Comment: What does prevents to replace PagingAndSortingReposito‌​ry to JpaRepository?

Comment: How will it help?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-jpa/1.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAndFlush(T)

Comment: It really works, I missed this solution. ...you should answer my question, thank i'll vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to switch to JpaRepository and use

```
eventRepository.saveAndFlush(event);
```

instead of `eventRepository.save(event)`.

Or

```
eventRepository.save(event);
eventRepository.flush();
```

It will force the repo to flush all pending changes to the database.

---

Also check whether you set `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` on your repo interface that turn the flush mode to NEVER (as described in the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactional-query-methods), or MANUAL as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10466591)) also for `save` methods. Perhaps this is the issue...