# What are advantages of using @Transactional(readOnly = true)?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data, spring-transactions

I am beginner and as I understand `@Transactional` simply make sure that all the internal work of a class or method annotated with `@Transactional` will be wrapped in one transaction and all of the calls from external sources will create a new transaction but why do we actually need these annotations in Repository below and what are advantages of using it with `readOnly = true` in common cases? This is Spring pet-clinic example application using **Spring** & **Hibernate** (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic).

```
/**
 * Repository class for <code>Pet</code> domain objects All method names are compliant with Spring Data naming
 * conventions so this interface can easily be extended for Spring Data See here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.query-creation
 *
 * @author Ken Krebs
 * @author Juergen Hoeller
 * @author Sam Brannen
 * @author Michael Isvy
 */
public interface PetRepository extends Repository<Pet, Integer> {

    /**
     * Retrieve all {@link PetType}s from the data store.
     * @return a Collection of {@link PetType}s.
     */
    @Query("SELECT ptype FROM PetType ptype ORDER BY ptype.name")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    List<PetType> findPetTypes();

    /**
     * Retrieve a {@link Pet} from the data store by id.
     * @param id the id to search for
     * @return the {@link Pet} if found
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    Pet findById(Integer id);

    /**
     * Save a {@link Pet} to the data store, either inserting or updating it.
     * @param pet the {@link Pet} to save
     */
    void save(Pet pet);

}
```

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614139/spring-transactional-read-only-propagation

Comment: Hello, if the answer helped you don't forget to accept/upvote it.

Comment: Note, that `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` annotation can be put on class/interface instead on each method. Than on "also writes" methods put just `@Transactional`, like in `SimpleJpaRepository` is done.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10466591) of Oliver Gierke - the Spring Data author:

> Reading methods like findAll() and findOne(…) are using
>   @Transactional(readOnly = true) which is not strictly necessary but
>   triggers a few optimizations in the transaction infrastructure
>   (setting the FlushMode to MANUAL to let persistence providers
>   potentially skip dirty checks when closing the EntityManager). Beyond
>   that the flag is set on the JDBC Connection as well which causes
>   further optimizations on that level.
>
> Depending on what database you use it can omit table locks or even
>   reject write operations you might trigger accidentally. Thus we
>   recommend using @Transactional(readOnly = true) for query methods as
>   well which you can easily achieve adding that annotation to you
>   repository interface. Make sure you add a plain @Transactional to the
>   manipulating methods you might have declared or re-decorated in that
>   interface.

Further reading:

- [Spring read-only transaction Hibernate optimization](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-read-only-transaction-hibernate-optimization/)
- [Read-write and read-only transaction routing with Spring](https://vladmihalcea.com/read-write-read-only-transaction-routing-spring/)