# Transaction timeout for Select query

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, ibatis, atomikos

I am using `AtomikosDataSource` and setting the datasource in Ibatis SqlSessionFactoryBean (db2 database). When my select query is running it is taking 15 seconds and returning the values, but i already have set below properties in my property files.

```
com.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout = 3000
com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout = 3000
```

Hence, i expect this transaction should reply me back as timeout error, but instead it keep running even after 3 seconds. But the same code works fine (that is throws timeout error for CREATE/UPDATE services of course these create/update services marked with annotation `@Transactional`. For select query service am not using `@Transactional` since it is just a fetch operation)

Note: I am using Spring & Atomikos 4.0.4.

Comment: If you don't have a tx, then there is also no timeout. Also you should really use a tx also for reading (in fact there is always a tx on the DB side in this case an implicit one!).

Comment: @M.Deinum do you mean that, i need to use "@Transactional" for select query service also? in order to get timeout?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

> For select query service am not using @Transactional

That's causing your issue, you need to mark your block as `@Transactional`.

> since it is just a fetch operation

Actually, setting `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` can trigger some optimisations in your transaction infrastructure.

See: [What are advantages of using @Transactional(readOnly = true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44986258/5037430)