# what is the purpose of @Transactional(read-only = true)

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I tried looking several SO questions and spring documents but still could not understand the significance of `@Transactional(read-only = true)`.

can it be only used for read only transactions or it can be use for something like below which actually read and write databse

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED
                          , rollbackFor= {Exception.class})
public void doMultipleOperation(MyObj obj) throws Exception{
//call delete DAO method
//call insert DAO method
//call select DAO method
}
```

I find  similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614139/spring-transactional-read-only-propagation) and multiple others on SO but I am looking for answer in more layman term.

Answer (score -1):

If you set a `Transaction` to `readonly = true`, then no, you will not be able to call any service methods that create, update or delete data from the database.  This is because the `flushMode` on the Hibernate session will be set to `NEVER`, and so you will be prevented from making any changes to your data.  Only selects will be allowed.

Comment: By defaut it is false, so just put `@Transactional`

Comment: Just to be clear. i will be using readonly = true only with propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED

Comment: Depends on your context, but you could also set propagation to `REQUIRES_NEW` which will create a new transaction in only a read-only context.  But again, I don't know how you are using it so you would have to explore all the options.  Take a look at: 

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html

Comment: I am sorry but i could not understand. If you look at my service method in my question, do you think I am doing it correctly ?

Comment: As explained by Spring-Data author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394857/how-to-use-transactional-with-spring-data/10466591#10466591
This is not necessarily true, transactional readony doesn't always prevent you to make modifications. That depends on the used database. It's mostly a marker that can be used for optimizations with certain ORMs.