# How to disable Transactional behaviour for read operations from SimpleJpaRepository?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, transactions

We have a Spring Boot application, that heavily relies on [SimpleJpaRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java) implementations for performing database CRUD operations.

Problem: The class is annotated with `@Transactional`, causing all methods called to be wrapped in an SQL transaction.

We would like our repositories to generate SQL transactions only for insert/update/delete operations, but not for select operations (unless they are called from another method annotated with `@Transactional`)

How can we setup our repositories to achieve this, and what what would be the less obvious effects? (I assume the class was annotated like this for a reason)

---

**Code and Logs**

Calling @Transactional method, expected 1 transaction, found 1 (OK)

```
@Transactional
public User readUser(int id){
    userRepository.findOne(id);
    roleRepository.findByUser(id);
}
```

SQL Profiler:

```
set implicit_transactions on 
exec sp_executesql N'select userentity0_.id as id1_45_, .....'
exec sp_executesql N'select roleassign0_.id as id1_36_, ....'
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN
```

Without @Transactional, expected no transactions, found 2, created by the repositories (BAD):

```
public User readUser(int id){
    userRepository.findOne(id);
    roleRepository.findByUser(id);
}
```

SQL Profiler:

```
set implicit_transactions on 
exec sp_executesql N'select userentity0_.id as id1_45_, .....'
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN

set implicit_transactions on 
exec sp_executesql N'select roleassign0_.id as id1_36_, ....'
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Do you call those methods from class or method, annotated with transactional?
You can test it with annotate one of those methods with transactional and set the propagation level to `NEVER `. Then it will throw an exception if you call it from transaction.

Comment: I don't want it to throw an exception. I want it to simply not create an implicit transaction for every query we make. Added detailed logs

Comment: How is your repository methods implemented? Do they use spring data repos?

Comment: Do you simply want no transactions at all for non-annotated methods?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai all repositories implement `SimpleJpaRepository` from spring-data-jpa

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai, your comment made me realize all my repositories extend `SimpleJpaRepository`, which is annotated with `Transactional` and is causing all the unwanted transactions for every method such as findAll, findOne, etc. I will update my question accordingly

Comment: Yes. That is why I wanted to clarify. Implemented methods in `SimpleJpaRepository` have Transactional annotation.

Comment: But `findBy` methods in `SimpleJpaRepository` does not have `@Transactional` annotation. My suspicion is even if spring data does not wrap it, hibernate will wrap it in transaction. I will experiment a bit more when I get time

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai findBy methods indeed do not have `@Transactional`, but if the class has `@Transactional`, all methods in the class also have it. The transaction disapears if I override the method and annotate the concrete class with `@Transactional(propagation=SUPPORTS`

Comment: I missed the class level annotation. It is the only way you get around with by redefining all the methods but that is a lot of work

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai, redefining all the methods is not a problem. Took me a few minutes thanks to IntelliJ's refactoring capabilities. Now I'm more interested in why the annotation exists on the class and what am I breaking by overriding the intended behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By default, CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional. For read operations, the transaction configuration readOnly flag is set to true.

   - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions
2. So your option is to redefine `findBy` methods with `@Transactional(propagation=SUPPORTS`)
3. You are not breaking anything by doing so but disabling some optimisations. See the answer by Oliver Gierke - the Spring Data author

- [How to use @Transactional with Spring Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394857/how-to-use-transactional-with-spring-data/10466591#10466591)

> Reading methods like findAll() and findOne(…) are using @Transactional(readOnly = true) **which is not strictly necessary** but triggers a few optimizations in the transaction infrastructure (setting the FlushMode to MANUAL to let persistence providers potentially skip dirty checks when closing the EntityManager). Beyond that the flag is set on the JDBC Connection as well which causes further optimizations on that level.

Comment: I assume if you have to do multiple `findBy` operations, to get repeatable read, you will wrap them in  `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` in your service layer

Comment: A tad simpler solution is to use `@EnableJpaRepositories(enableDefaultTransactions = false)`. 

It disables begin/commit SQL statements, but still bind an instance of `TransactionInfo` to the current thread (see last statement of `TransactionAspectSupport.prepareTransactionInfo()`) so no _javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress_ exception is thrown when calling a method without wrapping transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried annotating the desired methods with

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

`Execute non-transactionally, suspend the current transaction if one exists. Analogous to EJB transaction attribute of the same name.`

[Docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NOT_SUPPORTED)

Comment: This would suspend an already existing explicit transaction created by `@Transactional` and I don't want that. I only want to stop implicit transactions