# Transactional role in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I am using Java Spring Boot. In the following service function:

```
@Override
public QuestionDTO updateQuestion(Long id, QuestionDTO updateData) {
    Question question = questionRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());
    if(updateData.getText().length() > 0) {
        question.setText(updateData.getText());
    }

    List<Answer> newAnswers = new ArrayList<>();


    // Delete old answers
    // some filtering logic that would set isPresent variable

        // for i->0 -> arr.size
        if(!isPresent) {
            Long x = existingAnswer.getId(); // the answer with this id needs to be deleted
            answerRepository.deleteById(x);
        }
    
        // for i->0 -> arr.size
        {   
           // some logic to update existing answer entity
            existingAnswer.setIsCorrect(a.getIsCorrect());
            answerRepository.save(existingAnswer);
            justUpdate = true;
            break;
        }
        

        if(!justUpdate) {
            a.setQuestion(question);
            newAnswers.add(a);
        }
    

    LoggingController.getLogger().info("DONE UPDATE! Final array is:");
    question.setAnswers(newAnswers);

    // Save new array of answers for question
    Question updatedQuestion = questionRepository.save(question);
    return QuestionMapper.mapToQuestionDTO(updatedQuestion);
}
```

Question and Answers are both *entities* and my PostgreSQL db contains something like this:

**Question table**:

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "What is the capital of France?" |
| 2 | "How many countries..." |

**Answer table**:

| id | text | question_id (fk) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Answer A" | 1 |
| 2 | "Answer B" | 1 |

If I am using **@Transactional** above the function, all operations are executed how it should. If I am not using this annotation, the delete operation is not performed, others are. Why the delete is not working and others does and what is the exact effect of **@Transactional**?

Comment: Could you try to flush the session after answerRepository.deleteById(x); without transactional and write your results?

Comment: even if i call answerRepository.flush() after deleteById, it is still not deleting the entities

Comment: It should work if you add @Transactional to the delete method.

Comment: yes, it is working if I am adding @Transactional to the entire method too, but I am not sure why this is working like this

Comment: Where did existingAnswer come from? It is class-level variable?

Comment: Also could you enable SQL logging to see exactly what is being sent to the database when you do flush after delete without transactional? And show it to us. I believe that DELETE is not being sent for some reason

Comment: The method is not working because you didn't add transactional to the specified method I told you. It doesn't matter you add it on the entire method or class.

Comment: @RomanC his question is not "how to fix it" He wants to understand WHY this works this way man.

Comment: @cplusplus No, he wants to know why it didn't work, because he removed the annotation and confused why it didn't work. Hope, it is clear to you. If a delete method has an annotation then it should work. It is strange that he has created a repository without transactions.

Comment: Yes, so I want to know why it is a must to use @Transaction, because I have some other service methods like create or get where I am using only a repository method call (.find() and .save() ), but it does work correctly without the annotation. I suppose that if I have multiple repository calls, I need to use transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your using Spring data, to get to know more about the @transactional annotation read the following: [link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/transactions.html).
But in short it wraps your method, so it commits and can roll back JDBC operations if there would be an exception.

From what I understand is that if you want to update through multiple
repositories, you need to use the @Transactional annotation (answerRepository / questionRepository).

Comment: Ok, so the workflow needs to have this annotation in order to work correctly if multiple repositories are used? And why the delete method is affected? I mean if I was using only .save for both answerRepository and questiontRepository, the records do update in the database. The only problem is with deletion

Comment: As far as I know all updates / creates / deletes need a transactions. 
Most method from your CRUD repository enherit the @transactional already. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394857/how-to-use-transactional-with-spring-data
I am not 100% sure, what happens in your case,
As you are adjustin two entities wich are linked  (I think not clear from the question) there could be an issui.